# How can I root or make my partitions mounted rw?

Tags: rooting

I can edit firmware, how can I make my firmware rooted?

I tried changing all ro in init.rc to rw, but after boot they are mounted in ro. I guess the problem is there. Also I can't remount in adb. It says no errors but doesn't do the job. So all one-click root apps can't root, because they can't remount. How can I root or make partitions rw?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually a bug is exploited to temporarily get a chosen process running as root, that is used to remount the file system read write, either startup scripts are changed and/or suid binaries added, then the file systems are synced and remounted read only again and likely the device is rebooted.

You don't normally want to have the system partition writable on an android device, even when rooted - you only make it writable on the rare occasions when you are changing it.

EDIT-Summary of comments: It appears that /system on this device is cramfs, an inherently read-only compressed file system.  Likely a modified image would need to be generated on a PC and then flashed.

Search result for dealing with this problem on rockchip based devices:

http://www.androidtablets.net/forum/rockchip-based/439-how-unpack-repack-custom-firmwares-rockchip-rk28xx.html

Comment: I want to have partiton rw. Temporary or permanent - I dont care. But I cant remount even when I root.

I edited init script, changed all ro mount to rw, flashed and nothing changes (I checked script it has my changes but they dont work)

How can I get partition mounted as rw?

Comment: Please obtain a shell that you believe is running as root and post the output of 'ps | grep sh' and 'mount | grep system'  Also, which script file did you edit and what device are you working on?

Comment: ps | grep sh `http://pastebin.com/Q1PR2W3r`

Comment: mount | grep system `/dev/block/mtdblock4 /system cramfs ro 0 0

`

Comment: Well that explains your problem - cramfs is inherently read only (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cramfs ).  You'll probably need to make your modifications on a PC and flash a new image for system or initrd(which is normally glued onto the kernel, but who knows in your case). What device is this?

Comment: When I type su, it gives me # in android terminal emulator. I cat tether wifi with barnacle. But I cant remount partition. I tried to edit /init.rc, changed all mounts to rw, flashed, but nothing changes. Partitions are in cramfs. Also I have rooted 2.2 for this device. (this was 2.1). Rooted 2.2 is the rooted the same as 2.1, except mounts. Partitions are always mounted as rw, and I cant remount them to ro. (they also in cramfs) I want to get same result at 2.1.

Comment: How can I change partition type for system.img?

Comment: That's likely going to be quite difficult - more likely you need to recreate the image, which seems to be normal procedure for some devices.  I've asked you twice what device it is, why do you refuse to answer?

Comment: I dont know. This is chinese noname that I got for free.

Comment: Well try to figure out what brand the processor is, see if there's anything relevant in dmesg.  A little googling suggests that rockchip-based devices are a common example of something using a cramfs system, and provides instructions for dealing with it.

Comment: Yes, it is based on rockchip.